# Autoscroll during digitizing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I am relearning digitizing using QGIS after 30 years as a MAPINFO user.  There is an autoscroll option in Mapinfo that moves the screen automatically if your line needs to continue off the screen.  I can't find this in QGIS apart from the unwieldy use of the mouse scroll wheel.
NB: This question has been asked before (2017) but did not get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: It is not what you want, but you can press the spacebar while digitizing and pan the view as you like.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, it is nearly what I want and I will get used to it.  Still, just that little bit better in MAPINFO.

Comment: I use the arrow keys to pan when digitizing

Comment: Arrow keys move the map canvas by one quarter of its extent per pressing.

Comment: Thanks, friends, problem solved..  I personally prefer the spacebar over the arrow keys and I find the mouse scroll wheel quite unwieldy, but it would be marginally better if someone could make it automatic like it is in Mapinfo.

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly what you want, but you can press the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> while digitizing and pan the view as you like.

[image]

Comment: You can also click the scroll wheel to do the same thing.